# Stop a loop inside function in Python 3

Tags: python, function, loops

```
import random

def compareInput(n):
    if n == randomNumber: #Compares guess and the random number
        print("YAY!! you won the number was: " + n)
        return
        #(something) Loop should stop here.
    else:
        print("Wrong guess")



print("Guess the number") #Prints guess number duh!
randomNumber = str(random.randint(1,20)) #Generates a number between 1 and 20 and converts it to string
while True: #Input loop
    guess = str(input()) #Takes input and converts it to string
    if len(guess) > 0 and guess.isdigit() : #input must be a number and at lest 1 digit
        compareInput(guess) #Call compareInput function
    else:
        print("Wrong input")
```

How do I stop the while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `break` to break the closest `for` or `while` loop. In your case, you'd need to check the return value of `compareInput` in the `while` loop and then break or return as required.

```
import random

def compareInput(n):
                if n == randomNumber: #Compares guess and the random number
                        print("YAY!! you won the number was: " + n)
                        return True
                        #(something) Loop should stop here.
                else:
                        print("Wrong guess")
                        return False



print("Guess the number") #Prints guess number duh!
randomNumber = str(random.randint(1,20)) #Generates a number between 1 and 20 and converts it to string
while True: #Input loop
        guess = str(input()) #Takes input and converts it to string
        if len(guess) > 0 and guess.isdigit() : #input must be a number and at lest 1 digit
                if compareInput(guess): #Call compareInput function
                        break # We got the right guess!
        else:
                print("Wrong input")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# assumes Python 3.x
import random

def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            # not an int, try again
            pass

def is_correct(guess, target):
    if guess == target:
        print("YAY!! you won, the number was {}".format(target))
        return True
    else:
        print("Wrong guess")
        return False

def main():
    print("Guess the number")
    target = random.randint(1,20)

    while True:
        guess = get_int("What's your guess?")
        if is_correct(guess, target):
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Nice alternative, I like it too.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True: #Input loop
    guess = str(input()) #Takes input and converts it to string
    if len(guess) > 0 and guess.isdigit() : #input must be a number and at lest 1 digit
        compareInput(guess) #Call compareInput function
        break  ## you exit loop with break statement
    else:
        print("Wrong input")
```

Comment: This will always break even if the guess isn't right.

Comment: Yes, this will break the loop no matter what.

Comment: @andJusticeForAll it will break on correct input, to be precise

Comment: @m.wasowski: it will break whether the input is correct or not, "to be precise".

Comment: maybe i am too tired, but how it is going to break out on non-numeric values? just test it